# Compiling Erlang with wxWidgets enabled on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: build, compilation, erlang, osx-lion, wxwidgets

I am trying to compile the full `Erlang` package from source code on a Mac running Lion. The source code is latest release (`R14B04`). After

```
$ ./configure
```

I got the following:

```
wx: Can not combine 64bits erlang with wxWidgets on MacOSX, 
    wx will not be useable
```

So, I figured that the `wxWidgets` installed on my computer is 32bits. And one possible solution would be to build Erlang into 32bits binary. (wx is optional for the Erlang system to run, but I do really need it to be enabled.) So I did this:

```
$ ./configure --enable-m32-build
```

The configuring process went fine, so I started to build it.

```
$ make
```

After Erlang building itself happily for about three minutes, I got this

```
...
...
gen/wxe_derived_dest.h: In constructor ‘EwxMDIClientWindow::EwxMDIClientWindow(wxMDIParentFrame*, long int)’:
gen/wxe_derived_dest.h:699: error: no matching function for call to ‘wxMDIClientWindow::wxMDIClientWindow(wxMDIParentFrame*&, long int&)’
/opt/local/include/wx-2.9/wx/osx/mdi.h:142: note: candidates are: wxMDIClientWindow::wxMDIClientWindow()
/opt/local/include/wx-2.9/wx/osx/mdi.h:140: note:                 wxMDIClientWindow::wxMDIClientWindow(const wxMDIClientWindow&)
make[3]: *** [i386-apple-darwin11.2.0/wxePrintout.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [opt] Error 2
make[1]: *** [opt] Error 2
make: *** [libs] Error 2
```

Now I am stuck and don't know what to do. Has anybody successfully built Erlang on a Mac running Lion? Thank you.

Comment: For the time being, I use the Erlang GS, http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/gs/gs_chapter1.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download a Erlang pkg with correctly compiled wx from

https://www.erlang-solutions.com/downloads

If you want to use 64bit erlang VM with wx enabled you can give this variation

https://github.com/jvalduvieco/macports

a try.

Answer (score 1):

Erlang bindings sources seem to not have been updated for wxWidgets 2.9 yet. There `wxMDIClientWindow` ctor with this signature indeed doesn't exist (I'm going to check why and whether it makes sense to reintroduce it). A simple fix would be to replace it with a default ctor followed by a call to `CreateClient(parent, style)`.

Good luck!